# assigning a unique id for button

Tags: android, button, dart, flutter, boolean

suppose there exist a form and has two button ,i want one button to get disabled until all parameter is filled by user while other Enabled,for users to navigate to back panel.Is there exist a function to assign unique id to buttons?

```
Edit1:  Tried to disable one of the button,until all the text-form field in the page is touched by users,once user enters all the required parameters ,then the button gets enabled!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a unique id for that

```
FlatButton(Text('foo'), onPressed: areAllParametersFilled ? _onFooPressed : null),
FlatButton(Text('bar'), onPressed: !areAllParametersFilled ? _onBarPressed : null),
```

Comment: That's just a made up name. You need to complete that yourself. Because you didn't provide your code I can't know what suits your need. I assumed a `bool areAllParametersFilled;` that is set to `true` when all are filled and `false` otherwise. You'd need to set that yourself.